# Need help in sed command

Tags: linux, sed

I have the input

```
bmb/eng/case.bmb
```

and the output should be like:

```
bmb/case.bmb 
bmx/eng/case.bmx
```

The command i am using here is

```
$ echo bmb/eng/case.bmb | sed -E 's/.*/& &/;:a;s/([^ ]* [^\n]*)(bm)b/\1\2x/;ta;s~/~&eng&~2'
bmb/eng/eng/case.bmb bmx/eng/case.bmx
```

I have tied modifying the above command in multiple ways but i am not getting the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it's easier to do one thing at a time, so copy your line in the hold space with `h`, modify the line to produce the first output line, `p`rint it, then restore the save line with `g` and modify it to produce the second output line.

This allows you to have very simple replacements like `s/eng./&/` for the first part or `s_/.*/__` is the directory can have any name or could be core than one hierachy. And a simple `s/bmb/bmx/` for the second line.

```
echo bmb/eng/case.bmb | sed 'h;s_/.*/_/_;p;g;s/bmb/bmx/g'
```

produces the desired output.

You can use the hold space like the clipboard of your word processor. It's an extremely versatile and easy to use tool and such a pitty, that many `sed` users do not use it's power.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in one single search-replace command.

```
echo 'bmb/eng/case.bmb'|sed -r 's:^(bm)b(/[^/]+)(/.*\.\1)b$:\1b\3b\n\1x\2\3x:'
```

If you use `()` to group each matching piece, you can construct both lines of interest from those pieces, numbered \1, \2 and \3.