# Need help with Sed command with multiple replacements

Tags: text-processing, sed

I need a file with sed command
I have a file like this

```
amb/eng/hello.amb
```

and I need the output to be like below

```
amx/eng/hello.amx
amx-grk/eng/hello.amx
```

Could anyone please kindly help me?

Comment: It's unclear whether the criteria for duplicating and modifying the input should only affect lines that are _exactly_ `amb/eng/hello.amb`, or lines that start with `amb` and end with `.amb`, or whether you are only interested in filenames that are under a `eng` directory?

Comment: Did you try modifying the answer you accepted to [your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/751844/133219)? [edit] your question to show your attempt to solve the problem yourself so we can help explain whatever you were doing wrong so you can learn how to do things like this.

Comment: Please make sure to always explain what you need in _words_ not just by example. You need to explain how we can get from your input to the desired output. Should all lines be duplicated? What should be changed? `amb` only? Is it always the first thing on a line? What if we find `amb` in the line?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may try following:

```
sed 's/amb/amx/g' |  awk -F'/' '{print $1"/"$2"/"$3 " " $1"-grk/"$2"/"$3}'
```

e.g.

```
$ echo  'amb/eng/hello.amb' | sed 's/amb/amx/g' |  awk -F'/' '{print $1"/"$2"/"$3 " " $1"-grk/"$2"/"$3}'
amx/eng/hello.amx amx-grk/eng/hello.amx
```

Comment: Hi dgfjxcv, 
Thank you for your quick response.
Can you please insert new line in the above command like i should get file1 and file 2
amx/eng/hello.amx
amx-grk/eng/hello.amx

Comment: I got it Thank you so much dgfjxcv, added \n as below
echo  'amb/eng/hello.amb' | sed 's/amb/amx/g' |  awk -F'/' '{print $1"/"$2"/"$3 "\n" $1"-grk/"$2"/"$3}'

Comment: `awk` can do `g`lobal `sub`stitutions with its `gsub()` function as well, you generally don't need to pipe `sed` into `awk` as `awk` can do most of what `sed` can do.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `sed -e 's/amb/amx/gp' -e 's/amx/&-grk/' yourfile`.

Ex.

```
$ echo 'amb/eng/hello.amb' | sed -e 's/amb/amx/gp' -e 's/amx/&-grk/'
amx/eng/hello.amx
amx-grk/eng/hello.amx
```

Comment: The _only_ issue I have with this is that we don't know whether there are _other_ lines containing the substring `amx` that should _not_ be modified by that second expression. That and that you're changing `ambidextrous` and `ambrosia` into `amxidextrous` and `amxrosia`.

Comment: I agree with @Kusalananda : as written, the substitution rules are probably too amxiguous (and amx-grkiguous)...

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to [steeldriver's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/769621/116858), but is slightly more strict with the matching.

```bash
$ sed '\,^amb/\(.*\)\.amb$, { s,,amx/\1.amx,p; s/amx/&-grk/; }' file
amx/eng/hello.amx
amx-grk/eng/hello.amx
```

In the above command, we assume that we are looking for lines that start with `amb/` and end with `.amb`.  When such a line is found, the initial substitution command that is carried out changes these two substrings to `amx/` and `.amx`, respectively, and then outputs the modified line.  The second substitution changes the initial `amx` string (which we know is present at the start of the line) into `amx-grk`. The result of this second modification is outputted by the default output at the end of the cycle.

I'm using commas as the delimiter for the triggering regular expression at the start of the `sed` script and the `s` command inside the expression group in curly braces because I want to include a slash in the commands.

---

An alternative way of writing this exact command is to use `b` ("branch") as a way of *not* modifying any line that does not match the initial regular expression. This allows us to write the command as three separate expressions:

```bash
$ sed -e '\,^amb/\(.*\)\.amb$, !b' -e 's,,amx/\1.amx,p' -e 's/amx/&-grk/' file
amx/eng/hello.amx
amx-grk/eng/hello.amx
```